# Concave function proof

Tags: analysis, inequality, proof-writing, convex-analysis

I have a problem with this proof. I know I should use the fact, that f(x) = $x^p$ is concave but I am not sure how to do it at all. Here is the task: 
prove inequality $y^p - x^p \leq (y - a)^p - (x - a)^p$ provided that $0 \leq a \leq x \leq y$ and $0 \leq p \leq 1$. 
What I have noticed is that $x - a < x < y - a < y$ and that f(x) = $x^p$ is concave but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: It’s concave so for $x\leq y$, $f(x)\geq f(y)$. Since $x-a\leq x$ and $y-a\leq y$ the result follows.

Comment: Does it help to re-arrange the terms to $y^p - (y - a)^p \leq x^p - (x - a)^p$? If not, can you draw a sketch of these terms?

Comment: @LinAlg: $f(x) = x^p$ is concave, so for $x-a\leq x$ it follows $x^p\leq(x-a)^p$. Apply the same to $y$ and subtract the inequalities. Does this not work?

Comment: @D.Math But this function is increasing, so why "for ≤, ()≥()"?

Comment: We do not need convexity of any function but just observe that some function is decreasing.

Comment: @D.Math if $a\leq b$ and $c\leq d$, you cannot conclude $a-c \leq b-d$ (e.g., $5\leq 10$ and $0\leq 10$ but $5-0 \nleq 10-10$)

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan the inequality $f(x) - f(x-a) \leq f(y) - f(y-a)$ for $x\leq y$ holds for any convex function $f$ but not for all decreasing functions

Comment: @LinAlg: Read my proof. I am not talking about the function $f(t) = t^p$ itself. I am talking about $g(t) = (t+h)^p - t^p$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan for $g$ to be decreasing you need convexity of $f$, so your statement "We do not need convexity of any function" is simply incorrect

Comment: @LinAlg That $g$ is decreasing does not imply that $f$ is concave. I mean if $f$ and $g$ are related by $g(t) = f(t+h)-f(t)$ because $h\geq 0$ is fixed.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan are you sure about that? Dividide $g'(t)$ by $h$ and take the limit $h\downarrow 0$ to get $f''(x)\leq 0$ (if the limit exists).

Comment: $h$ is fixed at the very beginning and is not allowed to change. To be clear, $g_h(t) = f(t+h)-f(t)$. I mean by just assuming the fact: $g_h$ is decreasing for a particular $h$, we cannot conclude that $f$ is concave. Unless we are given that $g_h$ is decreasing for all $h>0$..

Comment: Convexity is more complicated and involving than monotonicity. If possible, just argue by monotonicity...

Answer (score 1):

Fix $h\geq 0$. Define $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(t) = (t+h)^p - t^p$.
Clearly $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. Note that $f'(t) = p [ (t+h)^{p-1} - t^{p-1} ] \leq 0$, so $f$ is decreasing.

In particular, for $h = y-x$, we have that $f(x) \leq f(x-a)$ and the results follows.

Comment: It is worth to point out that $0^0$ is undefined. (For the case that $p=0$, you may encounter the quantity $0^0$. The case that $p=0$ is treated separately.)